# How long to keep images on news articles

Tags: website-design, image, time

How long should one keep images of old articles?

I am working on a news site that has millions of articles and every single one has a featured image. Because of that, the site size is becoming too big(+20GB of images).

I noticed that some news sites remove images after a few months (not 100% sure, but I think NYTimes.com removes old images after ~3 months)

I understand that in a perfect world we ought keep all images forever. The truth is, after a few months no one reads old news articles any way, so why keep old images?

**EDIT:** We are going to moving the site to a could server with SSD and that storage is not cheap. I am sure there will be some fine tuning what images to keep for ever and what to remove after a period of time.
I know that some big news sites remove some images after a set period of time. I am looking for that set period of time.

Comment: When do you retire your articles?

Comment: What do you mean when? The articles will be live for as long as the site exist.

Comment: I mean when do  the articles disappear from search?

Comment: Never. All articles will are searchable. Where are you going with this?

Comment: Hard drives are cheap. Regardless, from a UX perspective, you'd keep the relevant content as long as you can.

Comment: I was thinking if the articles search date end date is set, then you could remove the articles along with images then

Comment: Are the images specifically relevant to the articles, or are they added to enliven the page. For example: a map that shows where an car chase occurred you should keep, but an image of the same type of car (i.e. not the actual car) you can quietly ditch.

Comment: @DA01, SSD are not cheap.

Comment: @Radi no, they are not. Which is why I'd probably use good ol' hard drives. :)

Comment: Well I am going to use SSD and that is why I need to lower my disk usage. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: I highly doubt there is an acceptable timeframe for deleting images. Once content is published online then that is it. Users aren't going to see an article without images and just think *'oh well, it is 2 years old so I don't care the pictures aren't there anymore'*. If people are still accessing your content then they will want all of it. Not giving them what they have come for is a bad User Experience, therefore there *isn't* an acceptable timeframe for deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

20GB of images is not that big of a deal and like @DA01 states in the comments, hard drives are cheap.  I just did a quick search and you can buy 2TB hard drives for under $100. That means cost *should not* be a factor.

The real question is: **What does it benefit a user for you to keep the images vs retiring them after a certain time period?** That is a really tough question to answer with any sort of certainty.

I would say that ultimately, it would depend on your audience and how articles are presented on your site. If your site doesn't have very much in terms of visual aids, keeping the images might do wonders for keeping a user's interest.  Retiring the images means the user would be presented with no visual aids, simply text, and that might overwhelm the user causing them to bounce, or leave your site.

---

**@DirkvB** brings up a good point:

> On top of that; what if the article is ABOUT the images. in that case, removing the image renders the article useless. Examples: articles about latest celebrity snapshots, new photos of a crashed airplane, missing/wanted persons, something art related, etc.

Comment: On top of that; what if the article is ABOUT the images. in that case, removing the image renders the article useless. Examples: articles about latest celebrity snapshots, new photos of a crashed airplane, missing/wanted persons, something art related, etc.

Comment: @DirkvB - Very true. Good point! Updated answer to include.

Comment: I am looking into moving the site to a cloud server with SSD and that is not cheap.

Comment: @Radi - Ok, so you want to spend [~$100 to ~$300 per month to host your site](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/pricing/)?  Is your site _that_ popular that it generates enough income to warrant paying that? Let's say it does, you can still store your images somewhere else.

Comment: @CodeMaverick I did not ask if economically it is a good idea. I asked for a time period after which it is not going to be a big deal from a UX stand point to not display images. Why is everybody trying to explain how to not use SSD and to store my images on a CND? I already know all that, thank you.

Comment: @Radi - I think you mean a CDN. Anyway, the reason people are talking to you about how not to use SSD is because you are stating that you the _reason_ you want to "retire" images is due to not wanting to pay for the disk usage. You have an A/B issue where you want to fix B because you are doing A, instead of fixing A thereby alleviating the need to fix B.

Comment: CDN is correct, thank you @CodeMaverick. Yes I want to lower the disk usage, so I can lower the cost for SSD. My A is +20GB of images and B is SSD cost. By lowering A will fix B. Again this is not a question of SSD vs HDD.

Comment: @Radi - That said, I did answer you from a UX perspective, albeit after I wrote 2 sentences about cost. The rest of my answer was dedicated to UX, and I think the conclusion is that removing the images period is a bad idea. That's just my conclusion though.

Comment: @Radi - Or you can say it this way: The cost of SSD disk space is A. Increasing disk space via images is B. By moving images to an HDD CDN fixes A and B at the same actually. This is because you are lowering SSD disk usage and cost by moving the image content off of the SSD to HDD.

Comment: This is getting out of hand :). I am using HDD CDN, but still have all images backed up on my server just in case.